# Disable Submit button until Input fields filled in

Tags: jquery, forms

Was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction with the following piece of jquery. I want to disable the submit button until my input fields have been filled in.

I have come up with this

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 if ($('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel').val().length > 0) {
  $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "false");
 }
 else {
  $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "true");
 }
});
```

but the button is permanently disabled, Even after filling in all the text input fields

Still learning Jquery and haven't used it for a while.. So any pointers appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your event binding is only on document ready.

So there is no listener when you change something.

Do this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#inputName').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('#inputEmail').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#inputTel').val().length    >   0) {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems better imo but you should use .prop() not .attr() for browser constitency

Comment: I know this is an old answer but this was helpful to me recently. I would like to add a suggestion. I would add (assuming that `inputTel` is the id of the last field before the `submit` button):  `$('#inputTel').keypress(function() {validate();});` to the line after `$('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel').change(validate);`. I think it helps with UX as it runs a the `validate()` function again whenever the user is in the "last" field and types, where as as it is the user might type something in the final field before submission and may be thrown off by the still disabled submit button.

Comment: @Douglas_Symb It is indeed a valid UX point. But I would not only put it on the last input. If an error occur (one input not filled) the keypress would be useful there as well. Instead, on keypress, I would add a debounce function that will trigger validate. So this would be good for UX and performance.

Comment: I do like the idea of a debounce better @Karl-AndréGagnon thanks for the feedback!

Comment: For those using `keypress`, I would add that keypress doesn't recognize backspace  and `keydown` executes for the 'previous state' (i.e before the key press), so I found `keyup` to be apt for my usecase

Answer (score 5):

Your current code is fine, but doesn't respond to user events, which is where you're tripping.

```
$('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 0){
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    }else{
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

**Edit** actually, this won't work. because one of those elements will caus ethe submit button to become enabled, regardless of the other ones. I'll hotfix momentarily.

**Edit** Here's the rough draft fix, it could probably be prettier, but will definitely be a good starting point.

```
var toValidate = $('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel'),
    valid = false;
toValidate.keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).data('valid', true);
    } else {
        $(this).data('valid', false);
    }
    toValidate.each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('valid') == true) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    if (valid === true) {
        $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);        
    }
});
```

[And here's your jsFiddle illustrating this method](http://jsfiddle.net/A7QtF/)

Comment: @Richlewis updated to be more portable and address your issue exactly.

Comment: jsfiddle not going to an example? thanks you for explaining, though still not working, maybe jsfiddle will help, thanks

Comment: do i need to use jquery 1.9.1 to make this work, im using 1.7.2 at the moment, not a problem if i have to

Comment: Ya, you should. At least don't wait to be in trouble in the future to upgrade your jquery version

Comment: @Richlewis you don't have to, as prop was added in 1.6, but the better question is, why wouldn't you use the latest stable release? Software receive updates for several reasons.

Answer (score 1):

change the property of a button and not the attribute...use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  if ($('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel').val().length > 0) {
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
  }
  else {
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

and i assume this make no sense since you don't have any event binding on it.. this will only check if the input has value in document.ready or not.. however event binding or not that depends on you.. but for these particular reason `prop()` was introduced in later version of jquery...

**updated**

after seeing the comments below,

```
$(function(){
  validate();
  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(validate); //you can use your multiple id selector instead of the attribute selector that i am using
});

function validate() {
  var inputvalue = $('input[type="text"]').filter(function (n) {
     return this.value.length > 0;
  })

  if (inputvalue.length == $('input[type="text"]').length) {
     $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
     $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

**this should work for any number of inputs with type as text (no need to change the javascript/jquery codes at all)**... here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHrdd/)

Comment: i didnt downvote...but as others have explained i wasnt binding to a users action

Comment: @Rohit Agrawal ya, for sure but at least is using .prop() not .attr() as your answer :)

Comment: @RohitAgrawal ... FYI `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.`

Comment: Also, this doesn't address the issue. This should have been a comment more than anything. You never detect any user-events, so how can you respond to changes? -1 from me.

Comment: @bipen that was incorrect totally prop and attr doesn't make any impact here on the result but the event binding makes

Comment: @RohitAgrawal have you read the jquery docs earlier ?? if yes then i guess you should see this too...`The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.` if not then here is the link to the doc http://api.jquery.com/prop/ ...and since you guys insisted for answer (correct i assume)..so here you go i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to run the if command again to enable that can be done on `change` event of input

```
function updateSubmit(){
  if ($('#inputName').val().length+$('#inputEmail').val().length+$('#inputTel').val().length > 2) {
     $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
   }
   else {
     $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
   }
}

$(document).ready(function (){
  updateSubmit();
  $('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel').on('change',function(){
   updateSubmit();
  });
});
```

Comment: if only one input is filled, what returns $('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel').val().length > 0 ?

Comment: ya got it i didn't considered the if statement, well above will return 1 if first is filled other wise 0

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to follow this thread to implement this with a custom **stripe** form.

This is my code:

```html
$(document).ready(function (){
  validate();
  $('#EMAIL, #FNAME, #LNAME, #card-element').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#EMAIL').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('#FNAME').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#LNAME').val().length    >   0  &&
        $('#card-element').hasClass('StripeElement--complete')
        ){
        $("button[type=button]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("button[type=button]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine until I added the `.hasClass` condition. The button just stays disabled!

Answer (score 0):

This code will check textbox, email and checkbox input types, works fine at my end and also if input fields are hidden, will check only visible fields.

```
  var register_disable = false;
  jQuery("#SUBMIT_BUTTON-ID").prop('disabled', register_disable);
  jQuery("input[type!='submit']").bind('keyup change', function () {
    jQuery("input[type='text'], input[type='email']").not(':input:hidden').each(function () {
      if (jQuery(this).val().trim() == "" || !$("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')) {
        register_disable = true;
      }
    });
    jQuery("#SUBMIT_BUTTON-ID").prop('disabled', register_disable);
    register_disable = false;
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the form onsubmit.  Nice and clean.  You don't have to worry about the change and keypress events firing.  Don't have to worry about keyup and focus issues.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp

```
<form action="formpost.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateCreditCardForm()">
   ...
</form>

function validateCreditCardForm(){
    var result = false;
    if (($('#billing-cc-exp').val().length > 0) &&
        ($('#billing-cvv').val().length  > 0) &&
        ($('#billing-cc-number').val().length > 0)) {
            result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```