# Datepicker has value despite appearing empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working on a table in which I want an 'add-row' link to become available only when several inputs are non-empty. I've adapted this ([Disable Submit button until Input fields filled in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761696/disable-submit-button-until-input-fields-filled-in)) however in my case my datepicker (jQuery UI datepicker that is) input has value even when it's empty. I read somewhere that the datepicker is automatically POSTing a value regardless of whether a value has been specified. This defeates the purpose of my function.

Here's my markup:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="date"><input class="datepicker" name="date-01" value="" /></td>
        <td class="hours"><input class="hours" name="hours-01" value="" /></td>
        <td class="rate"><input  class="rate" name="rate-01" value="60.00" /></td>
        <td class="date-total"><input class="date-total" name="date-total-01" value="" /></td>
        <td class="add-delete-row">
            <a href="#" class="delete-row" title="Delete row">Delete</a>
            <a href="#" class="add-row" title="Add a row">Add Row</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

... and the pertinent js:

```
// 1. Datepicker options/format:
$('.datepicker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
}); // END Datepicker

    checkRow();
    $('.hours-table').on('blur', 'input', checkRow); // same results using either keyup or change; apparently empty datepicker input has a value
    });

function checkRow() {
    //if (  $('input.datepicker').not(':empty') &&
    if (    $('input.datepicker').val().length > 0 &&
            $('input.hours').val().length > 0 &&
            $('input.rate').val().length > 0 &&
            $('input.date-total').val().length > 0  ) {
        $('.add-row').show();
        alert ($('input.datepicker').val());
    }
    else {
        $('.add-row').hide();
    }
}
```

I set up a jsfiddle (jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sheckyvansheck/4HPfe/27/) but can't get the datepicker to work which of course makes it worthless.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

cheers, svs

Comment: it seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m9wyd/1/

Comment: Bizarre. Confirming the code snippets are the same as what I'm running on my local server, where it still fails. Baffled.

Comment: Instead of emptying the value, you may want to try disabling it: `$('input.datepicker').prop('disabled', true);`. This will prevent it from sending the value when submitting the form.

Comment: Thx @xiankai, but I do not want the datepicker disabled. The problem is that the datepicker has a value which is defeated my function despite not having entered a value in the datepicker input.

Answer (score 0):

DOH! In the version I've been working on on my local server, there's another datepicker input which precedes the 'hours' table. Ergo, my checkRow function required the following selector:

```
function checkRow() {
if ($('.hours-table input.datepicker').val().length > 0 && ...
```