# Javascript & Forms

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently trying to do a form that requires the user to enter valid information.

For instance Here's a classic form: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKq3p/)

I want the user to put name and address. But I want the button to be unclickable until the user inputs his Name and his Email(in a correct form).

Is there any property that lets me access if a button is unclickable? Something like:

```
function validateButtonSubmit {
    if (validateEmail(email)) {
        if (validateName(name)) {
            document.getElementById("submitButton").clickable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Whats the best way to accomplish this, am I going in the right direction?

Comment: You should look into jquery validator, it makes validating input on the client side so much easier than all these if statements (which, assuming your functions are correct, is the proper way to do it, aside from the clickable part, change that to disabled).

Comment: you can `disable` the submit button. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931688/disable-enable-submit-button-until-all-forms-have-been-filled

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable/Enable Submit Button until all forms have been filled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931688/disable-enable-submit-button-until-all-forms-have-been-filled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably shorten this up without the nesting if you wanted:

```
function validateButtonSubmit() {
    var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    btnSubmit.disabled = !(validateEmail(email) && validateName(name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could call removeAttribute() on the element and then call setAttribute after you've validated the form:

```
var button = document.getElementById('submitButton');
button.removeAttribute('click');
// validation stuff 
button.setAttribute('click', submitForm());
```

Comment: As submit can be bypassed in a number of ways, this is a really bad solution and not easily maintained. Best to use one of the many validation patterns that already exist.